# flipped 2D array not filling properly

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array

My 2D array will not fill properly I want the original array to stay unmodified, which it does, but then the next array to be flipped. For example 111, 222, 333 should be 333, 222, 111. If anyone could help it would be appreciated.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
      int rows = 0, cols = 0;
      System.out.println("Please enter the size or your rows first and then columns:");
      Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
      rows = input.nextInt();
      cols = input.nextInt();
      int [][] my2DArray = new int [rows][cols];
      System.out.print("Now fill the array with the numbers you would like: ");
      for(int i = 0; i < my2DArray.length; i++)
       {
          for(int j = 0; j < my2DArray[i].length; j++)
       {
          my2DArray[i][j] = input.nextInt();
       }
        System.out.println("");
       }



      System.out.println("Here is the origional unmodified array.");
      for(int i = 0; i < my2DArray.length; i++)
      {
      for(int j = 0; j < my2DArray[i].length; j++)
      {
          System.out.print(my2DArray[i][j] + " ");
      }
      System.out.println("");
      }

      flipMy2DArray(my2DArray);

      }

 public static int[][] flipMy2DArray(int[][] inMy2DArray)
 {
  int [][] flipMy2DArray = new int [inMy2DArray.length][inMy2DArray.length];

  for(int row = flipMy2DArray.length-1; row > 0; row--)
  {
     for(int cols = 0; cols < flipMy2DArray[row].length; cols++)
     {
         flipMy2DArray[row][cols] = inMy2DArray[row][cols];
     }
     System.out.println("");
  }

  for(int row = 0; row < flipMy2DArray.length; row ++)
  {
      for(int cols = 0; cols < flipMy2DArray[row].length; cols++)
      {
          System.out.print(flipMy2DArray[row][cols]+ " ");
      }
      System.out.println("");
  }



       return flipMy2DArray;
   }
}
```